# How to used a http conection for send a string like email to a server? on Blackberry

Tags: http, blackberry

I have a little trouble, i need to create a way to send a string to a server, i a kinda system of complains

```
            try {
                String errMsg = validateData();
                if(errMsg == null){
                    String mailURL = CLIENT_CONTACT_URL_MAIL_SERVICE;
                    mailURL = Utils.replaceAll(mailURL, "@toAddress", TO_DEFAULT_ADDRESS);
                    String content = "";
                    content = "Nombre: " + this.names.getText() + "\n";
                    content += "Apellido: " + this.surname.getText() + "\n";
                    content += "Email: " + this.email.getText() + "\n";
                    content += "Telefono: " + this.phone.getText() + "\n";
                    content += "Mensaje: " + this.complains.getText() + "\n";
                    mailURL = Utils.replaceAll(mailURL, "@bodyContent", URLUTF8Encoder.encode(content));
                    Utils.getWebData(mailURL, this);
                }else{
                    Dialog.alert(errMsg);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.logErrorEvent("Error while sending client contact mail");
            }
            break;
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking how to send an HTTP request?

Comment: I am a novice developer, I need to create an http post as android, sending out a questionnaire to email server

Answer (score 0):

The following code will send data to server.

```
        static String responce;
        static String httpURL;
        httpURL=your_server_url+content;  //here add your server url like- http://www.google.com/ then append the string content.
        try {
        if ((WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
                && RadioInfo
                        .areWAFsSupported(RadioInfo.WAF_WLAN)) {
            httpURL += ";interface=wifi"+";ConnectionTimeout=30000";
        }
        //Dialog.alert(httpURL);
        HttpConnection httpConn;
        httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(httpURL);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        DataOutputStream _outStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConn.openDataOutputStream());
        byte[] request_body = httpURL.getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < request_body.length; i++) {
            _outStream.writeByte(request_body[i]);
        }
        DataInputStream _inputStream = new DataInputStream(
        httpConn.openInputStream());
        StringBuffer _responseMessage = new StringBuffer();
        int ch;
        while ((ch = _inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            _responseMessage.append((char) ch);
        }
        String res = (_responseMessage.toString());
        responce = res.trim();
        //Dialog.alert(responce);
        httpConn.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Dialog.alert("Connection Time out");
    }

    return responce;
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn`t work, this is the string i sent from my app on iOS, orgid=%@&retURL=%@&00Na000000AlkMe=%@&name=%@&apellido_paterno=%@&apellido_materno=%@&email=%@&lada=%@&phone=%@&type=%@comments=%@&subject=%@&recordType=%@&description=%@",@"00D30000001HUqw",@"http://www.examplo.com/mx/conocenos/contactanos/gracias.html",@"c",nameTextField.text,fLastNameTextField.text,sLastNameTextField.text,emailTextField.text,ladaTextField.text,phoneTextField.text,typeOfComentTextField.text,commetTextView.text,@"Caso desde App Movil IOS",@"01230000001J2r6",description

Comment: I need to send this content with a header in blackberry, please help

Comment: VM:THMNx=127,r=0x11FE7C00,t=net.rim.vm.MessageQueue
VM:THMNx=31,r=0x10EAFC00,t=java.util.TaskQueue
VM:THMNx=65,r=0x11FB0000,t=java.lang.Object
VM:THMNx=65,r=0xCFB6400,t=net.rim.device.api.crypto.tls.tls10.TLSRecordProtocol
VM:THDRr=native
VM:THDLv=0
VM:PISVt=1,h=1778,id=d15a33128dfbb5d9
Exit App(183)
Detected background switch for App(183) who has NO tunnels open - defocus NOT called
TID:unable to execute in the app